# Tesla based server for web server?

Tags: mysql, apache, webserver, tesla

I just want to know if I can use a tesla based server (with a Tesla GPU to be clear) as a web server just like a normal server for example by installing apache and mysql?

If it's possible, I would like to know if it will use efficiently the power of the Tesla GPU, doing almost the same work as the CPU??

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: I assume the server in question has GPUs in addition to normal CPUs?  Software typically must be specially written to run on GPUs.  Apache and MySQL have not been -- they'd run on the CPUs without utilizing the GPUs at all.

Comment: Ohh I see! So unless I build a php server client from ground up, its useless to get one of those servers. Thank you for the informations

Answer (score 1):

The problem is rather to have a Web server use Tesla CPUs. This would require using specialized compilers or libraries (Cuda, OpenCL, etc.).